# How to pipe into N processes in bash

Tags: bash

Given a long list of input lines (say a log file), I want to launch N processes and have them share the load of processing the input in parallel. So if N = 3 I want only 3 processes to be launched so that each processes receives a 3rd of the input to its stdin:

```
process 1: line1, line4, line7...
process 2: line2, line5, line8...
process 3: line3, line6, line9...
```

I thought `xargs -n1 -P3` was supposed to accomplish this, but I guess it just makes sure that no more than 3 processes run ***at the same time*** while I'm interested in launching no more than 3 processes in total.

Comment: Set up 3 processes, each reading from a named pipe. Have `awk` read the log files and send successive lines to successive named pipes.

Comment: I think `xargs` can do this. You have a two-variable equation. `xargs -nX -PY < input` where X ✕ Y = the number of rows. Of course, that doesn't guarantee that the rows will be processed in order or interpolated the way you specify, but all rows will be processed and split evenly between processes nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in {0..10}; do echo $i; done | { # simulates input

  temp_dir=`mktemp -d /tmp/parallel_test.XXX`

  N=3

  pipes=$(eval echo `echo $temp_dir/{1..$N}`)
  mkfifo $pipes

  keep_pipes_open=$temp_dir/keep_pipes_open
  touch $keep_pipes_open

  for pipe in $pipes; do
    sed -e "s/^/pipe ${pipe##*/}: /" < $pipe & # sed simulates the proccess you want to run
    while [ -f $keep_pipes_open ]; do sleep 1; done > $pipe &
  done

  typeset -i i=1
  while read line; do
    echo "$line" > $temp_dir/$i
    i=$((i % N + 1 ))
  done

  rm $keep_pipes_open
  wait
  rm -rf $temp_dir
}
```

Output:

```
pipe 1: 0
pipe 1: 3
pipe 1: 6
pipe 1: 9
pipe 2: 1
pipe 2: 4
pipe 2: 7
pipe 2: 10
pipe 3: 2
pipe 3: 5
pipe 3: 8
```